# Best way to check if a field exist in an Elasticsearch document

Tags: elasticsearch, exists

What is the best way to check if a field of a document in elasticsearch exists? I can't find anything in the documentation.

For example if this document doesn't have the field/key "price" I don't want to return in the result.

```
{
    "updated": "2015/09/17 11:27:27",
     "name": "Eye Shadow",
     "format": "1.5 g / 0.05 oz",
}
```

What I can do?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use the [`exists` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-filter.html) combined with a [`bool/must` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html) like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "price"
              }
            },
            ...     <-- your other constraints, if any
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**DEPRECATED (since ES5)** You can also use the [`missing` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-filter.html) combined with a [`bool/must_not` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "missing": {
                "field": "price"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But exists is not like IS NULL of SQL? if doesn't check the "field" it checks the value of the field. Perhaps I have missunderstood the docs. @Val

Comment: If your document doesn't have a `price` field, then it cannot have a `price` value either, so the document without `price` field will not be matched.

Comment: Val yes I could do it, It was a problem with my data and as well I wasmissunderstanding the documentation. It's working. Thanks @Val.

Comment: this is now deprecated. please check @Devi's answer

Comment: @Dexter `missing` is deprecated, but not `exists`

Answer (score 29):

The `exists` filter has been replaced by `exists` **query** from ES 2.1, though the working of it is the same. Also, the missing filter is removed and missing query deprecated.

To get all docs which have a particular field,

```
"bool": {
    "must": {
        "exists": {
            "field": "my_field"
        }
    }
}
```

and to get all docs which does NOT have a particular field, use it with `must_not` like this

```
"bool": {
    "must_not": {
        "exists": {
            "field": "my_field"
        }
    }
}
```

Elastic docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-missing-query.html

Answer (score 24):

You can directly do

```
{
    "query": {
        "exists": {
            "field": "fieldName"
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanna add some match too, then you can go for

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "fieldName": "value"
                }
            },
            {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "fieldName"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html

Answer (score 9):

You can use exists filter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "status"
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Regards,
Alain

Answer (score 8):

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "exists" : { "field" : "price" }
    }
}
```

source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html

Comment: this is the right one for the latest 7.16 version