# parsing_exception: no [query] registered for [filtered]

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch, laravel-5.3

I am trying to find all the results which is not contain a field 'open_location'. I am using the below code. But it gives me the error for print result. The error is,
parsing_exception: no [query] registered for [filtered]

I have seen this question for my solution,
[Best way to check if a field exist in an Elasticsearch document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949321/best-way-to-check-if-a-field-exist-in-an-elasticsearch-document)
But

Please help me...

```
$index_name=$db_name.'_temp_traking';

    $para= [
        'index' => $index_name,
        'type' => $index_name,
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'filtered' => [
                    'filter' => [
                        'bool' => [
                            'must_not' => [
                                'missing' => [
                                    'field' => 'open_location'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $response = $client->search($para);
```

Comment: Which version of elastic are you using?

Comment: elastic version 5

Comment: Did you make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The filtered query is deprecated and removed in Elastic 5, which I guess is what you are using. Also, you say you're looking for docs that do NOT contain the field, but your code says it 'must not' be 'missing'.

If you need the field not to exist, try this:

```
 "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "open_location"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```