# Elasticsearch get documents where a property is not empty

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

If I want to return all the documents which have an empty property (`IMG`) I can do something like that:

```
GET something/_search/?
{
  "query": {
    "term": {"IMG": ""}
  }
}
```

It works because `IMG` is a keyword. If I want the *exact inverse*, which means get all the documents where `IMG` is not null, what should I type? Is there an "inverse" of `term` query?

In other words, is there a way with Elasticsearch to **get documents where a property is not empty**?

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949321/best-way-to-check-if-a-field-exist-in-an-elasticsearch-document/32949472#32949472

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. It does not really help, because these answers check for **existence**, not **emptiness**.

Comment: Sorry, so you mean "the property is not the empty string"?

Comment: @Val Yes. BTW I just found a solution and posted an answer right below. Feel free to comment, edit, or post your own answer!

Comment: I've posted one, too ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your solution above would also return documents where the field is null, which you don't want I guess. So the correct solution would be this one:

```
GET memoire/_search/?
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "test"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "test.keyword": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution. Use `must_not` with `term` query. This should work:

```
GET memoire/_search/?
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "term": {"IMG.keyword": ""}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you have `must` instead of `must_not`

Comment: @Val Woops! +1 thank you! (I was just checking with kibana the must_not then the must to be sure, and I posted the wrong one!). Edited, fixed!

Comment: See my solution in order to make sure that you don't return docs with `IMG: null`.