# ElasticSearch filter query for having null value

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I want to filter data from elasic search document like
documents which is having blank list.
HOw can i achieve that.
Suppose i want this results.

1)
    {
        name:'vipul',
        gender:[]
    }

this is having blank list

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949321/best-way-to-check-if-a-field-exist-in-an-elasticsearch-document/32949472#32949472 (hint: use `bool/must_not/exists`)

Answer (score 12):

You can combine a `bool` query with a `exists` query like so:

```
"bool": {
    "must_not": [
        {
            "exists": {
                "field": "gender"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```